# New error with Swift 1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just upgraded to Xcode 6.1 and the newest version of Swift. My previously working code:

```
let window :UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
```

now gets an error message in Xcode:

`Value of optional type 'UIWindow?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Xcode suggests changing the code to the following but I now get a crash when the code is called while in use.

`let window :UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!`

**Solved**

**This is what worked for me:**

```
var window :UIWindow? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
if (window != nil) {
    self.center = window!.center
}
window?.addSubview(self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the type of your variable to be an optional to match the type of the `keyWindow` property:

```
let window :UIWindow? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
```

You get the crash since you're telling Swift *Unwrap this variable, I know it's not nil.* Except, at that point, it *is* nil.

The alternative is to use conditional unwrapping:

```
if let window :UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
    // Access "window" here.
}
```

Comment: I tried that but then on the following lines when I try to access the windows center property I get an error that UIWindow does not have a member named 'center'.

Comment: How do you access the property? It should be `window?.center` (which will return an `CGRect?`). Or you use conditional unwrapping, see my updated answer.

Comment: Still had issues with access using ?. Switched to conditional unwrapping and it fixed the errors. I'm still crashing though so maybe the crash it unrelated to this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The issue seems to be here: ```self.center = window?.center;``` I'm getting a CGPoint unwrapped error.

Comment: Got it! Needed a combination of both your solutions. I've posted my code in the question.